# How can I call and a method and insert a seed?

Tags: java

I think i got the first method correct, I'm just not sure how to go about calling the first method in my second method and use a seed. When using random.nextInt how do i use the seed part is what im understanding the least in this.

```
public class Compass {
    // TODO - write your code below this comment.
    // You will need to write two methods:
    //
    // 1.) A method named numberToDirection, which
    //     takes an int and returns a String representing
    //     either a direction, or the string
    //     "Out of range: " + x
    //     ...where x is the input int
    //
    // 2.) A method named randomDirection, which
    //     takes a long and returns a String.
    //     The long should be used as a seed value with
    //     which to generate a random number between
    //     0-7, inclusive.  This random number should
    //     then be used as a parameter to a call to
    //     numberToDirection.  randomDirection should
    //     return the result of the call to
    //     numberToDirection.
    //     To be clear, randomDirection MUST CALL
    //     numberToDirection!
    public static String numberToDirection(int x) {
        switch (x) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("North");
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Northeast");
        case 2:
            System.out.println("East");
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Southeast");
        case 4:
            System.out.println("South");
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Southwest");
        case 6:
            System.out.println("West");
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Northwest");
        default:
            System.out.println("Unknown direction" + x);
        }
    }

    public static String randomDirection(long seed) {
        switch (numberToDirection(random.nextInt(7) + 1)) {

        }
    }
```

Right above here is where I am stuck.

```
    // DO NOT MODIFY main!
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter seed: ");
        long seed = input.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Random direction: " + randomDirection(seed));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have  **NOT** got the first method correct. It must return a String.

Comment: so instead of system.out.println i should use return "..." right?

Comment: When do you initialize the random variable? The Random class has a constructor besides the default that takes a long seed argument

Comment: @drgundo Yes, that's definitely one way to do that.

Comment: What do u mean by initialize random variable? As in something like Random random = new Random(seed); ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `Random` object and provide the constructor with the `seed` value as the starting point for your random number generator. After that you can simply call `nextInt()`.

```
public static String randomDirection(long seed)
{
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    int direction = r.nextInt(8);
    String dirAsString = numberToDirection(direction);
    // work with dirAsString here...
}
```